# Creating a circle out of tiles

Tags: java, geometry, tiles, trigonometry

This is my first attempt at creating a 2D game, so my code probably isn't as efficient as it could be. Anyway, I tried creating a method to create circles out of my tiles. The point of this method is to create  circular dirt patches across my screen. Here is a bit of my code:

```
private void generateDirt(int x, int y) {

    int dirt = 3;
    int radius = random.nextInt(7) + 3;

    for (int i = radius; i > 1; i--) {
        for (int angle = 0; angle < 360; angle++) {
            double theta = Math.toRadians(angle);

            // Broken Line to solve jutting blocks
            // if (theta % Math.PI == 0) theta = 0;

            tiles[(int) (x + radius * (Math.sin(theta) * Math.cos(theta)))
                    + (int) (y + radius
                            * (Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(theta))) * width] = dirt;
        }
        radius--;
    }

}
```

If I comment out the part where I decrease the radius, and draw just a single circle outline (comment out the outermost for loop(int i = radius...) then the circle is drawn perfectly, except for these two strange tiles jutting out in the side. Sometimes the jutting block is on the right side (I thought it was when it was equal to pi / 2) and on the bottom side as well. But the main problem is that when I attempt to fill the circle by decreasing the radius, the circle...well... becomes a square. It loses its round shape and develops very rigid corners.

I worked on this pretty late, I'm not even sure if my math is correct. TBH, I just kinda threw in the trig functions at random and finally got something that looked like a circle. If you can help me identify what is wrong, or tell me a better way to do this, please let me know! Thanks for the help!

*Also, the radius is actually the diameter (I counted), I need to change the name...

Comment: Have you tried to debug your solution? Just place some breakpoints and you can watch step by step what is happening. If you are new to programming, you should be learning how to debug your code. Really handy. You can find many tutorials online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the answer to my own question. It turns out I don't need to convert my angles to radians. In fact, that just messes up the coordinates. Just using the "angle" instead of "theta" variable fixes the problem.